# serialize map of maps to dyanmodb to json

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

To attribute Map below in a class that i want to save and read from Dyanmodb, using DynamoDBMapper.

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Transition>> twf;
```

```
public class Transition {

    public String fst;
    public Permission pm;
    public List<Action> ac;
}

public class Action {
    private String mdl;
    private String dsc;
    private String nm;
    // email address or any other data
    private Map<String, String> data;
}
```

i have tried DynamoDBTypeConverted to convert to String, that results in json string that has " escaped as \" and unreadable in dyanmodb. I wanted to store as json

I implemented with understanding that Dyanmodb supports Map, but i still get error :
Exception processing message: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted

```
    public class TimeSheetWorkFlowConverter implements
            DynamoDBTypeConverter<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Map<String, Transition>>> {

    @Override
        public Map convert(Map<String, Map<String, Transition>> object) {
            // Map obj = mapper.readValue(object, Map.class);
            String newJson = null;
            Map objectJson = null;
            try {
                newJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
                objectJson = mapper.readValue(newJson, Map.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return objectJson;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Map<String, Map<String, Transition>> unconvert(Map<String, Object> object) {
            Map<String, Map<String, Transition>> wf = new HashMap<>();

            if (object != null && !object.isEmpty())
                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : object.entrySet()) {

                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Map<String, Transition> value = mapTransition(entry.getValue());
                    wf.put(key, value);
                }

            return wf;
        }
```

Comment: You might seriously consider using a nested `m` type attribute instead; you'll gain the ability to index, and the built-in tooling will be a bit easier to use.

Comment: Hi @chrylis please elaborate